# Can not call value of non-function type '[Item]'

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data, error-handling, swift2

I added core data to one of my apps and now I have this error "cannot call value of non-function type '[Item]'". Item is my coredata class.

```
var items = [Item]()


let newItem = items(name: nameTextField!.text, inManagedObjectContext: self.coreDataDB!)
```

Please, any information is valid. Thanks !

Comment: What is `items`? it is a class, a variable, or a struct? The error message tells me that `items` might be a `[Item]` and you are trying to call a function `items(name: , inManagedObjectContext:  )`

Comment: It looks to me that you're using `items` from your array declaration to construct your class instance instead of using `Item(name: nameTextField!.text, inManagedObjectContext: self.coreDataDB!)`.

Answer (score 0):

So you defined a `var` `items` as an array of `Items` which does containan empty array of `Items`.

Fine.

Then you try to use `items` as if it were a function

```
items(name: nameTextField!.text, inManagedObjectContext: self.coreDataDB!)
```

Of course it won't work.

Since `items` is an array you can use it like this

```
items.count
items.removeFirst()
items.last
```

Please refer to the [official Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107) for the full list of methods available into an array.